# hiredis c socket

Tags: c, redis

```
reply = redisCommand(rcontext,"HGET %u %u",env->cr[3] ,KeyHandle);
if(reply == NULL)
{
printf("in preNtDeletKey rediscommand error ! and the err type is %d the string is %s \n" ,rcontext->err,rcontext->errstr)";
}
```

Here I got a error , the reply return NULL
the output is

in preNtDeletKey rediscommand error ! and the err type is 1 the string is **Interrupted system call**

I use this in my project . And i grep in the hiredis source don't find Interrupted system call
I want to know what the reason to cause a Interrupted system call
How hiredis write the string to the redisContext (because I don't find in the sourec)

How we avoid the Interrupted system call ?

Comment: Good try, but this question needs more research if you want people smarter than me to help you. My guess is that you are using Redis database? https://github.com/antirez/hiredis (we shouldn't have to guess that) and some minimal info about the system, like I guess Linux. I tried to answer, but guessing is hard.

Comment: No idea how this would happen. Maybe you should try to use "async" interface of hiredis to avoid such error.

Comment: I use fedora , redis 2.6 hiredis 0.10.1 . I am using qemu to hook some Ntfunction in windows . This mean I will register some func ,if One Ntfunction was called .this function will be called. What I do is get some datas and save it to the db then analyze it. I first connect the db  in the main func and get the redisContext .In Some c files I will use the redisContext to do some redisCommand .Indeed get some data in db (this mean it work well first) Then it cann't work . Didier Spezia 's answer give me some suggestions I will have a try. But I just wonder.it can't work later. Why can work first

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The hiredis package marshals your command using the Redis protocol, and sends it to the Redis server. It then synchronously waits for the reply.

You will find the functions dealing with the sockets in the [hiredis.c](https://github.com/antirez/hiredis/blob/master/hiredis.c) file:

```
int redisBufferRead(redisContext *c)
int redisBufferWrite(redisContext *c, int *done)
```

In these functions, the EAGAIN error is handled, but not the EINTR error which corresponds to the "Interrupted system call" message.

The consequence is any Unix signal, received by the process when hiredis is doing a write or (more likely) a read operation, can interrupt the operation and cause this error.

You need first to understand which kind of signal the application receives. Depending on the nature of the signal and the application, there are various ways to handle this situation:

- masking or deferring signal handlers before doing Redis calls
- binding the signal to an event loop handler (if any) to avoid the signal to be processed when it is not expected
- dedicate a given thread to handle all signals (and avoid any Redis calls in this thread)
- using the SA_RESTART option (in sigaction) to tell the system to replay interrupted system calls automatically
- just try to do the operation again (it might not be possible though)

Personally, I would favor hiredis to handle the situation in a more graceful way (i.e. processing EINTR just like EAGAIN).

**UPDATE:**

The EAGAIN error is normally returned in two situations:

- when the non blocking mode has been activated by calling redisConnectNonBlock or
  redisConnectUnixNonBlock()
- when the connection is in blocking mode (default) and the redisSetTimeout() method has been called to set a timeout

Please note calling the redisSetTimeout() functions on client side just set the SO_RCVTIMEO and SO_SNDTIMEO [properties of the socket](http://linux.die.net/man/7/socket). It is completely unrelated to the timeout defined in the Redis configuration file which is a server side idle timeout (Redis server being able to close a connection if it has been inactive for more than N seconds).

Getting EAGAIN in the second situation means the Redis instance is not responsive enough for the provided timeout. You may want to simply increase the timeout or investigate further the latency issues on Redis server side.

Comment: Use `reply=redisCommand(rcontext,(rcontext,"HGET %u %u",env->cr[3] ,KeyHandle) if(reply == NULL){ printf("error is %d",errno );}`  I got the most error is 11 (EAGAIN) . I think this error was create by the redisCommand itself not caught from other process or system .That's mean if i masking the signal doesn't help if it create by itself Which may cause by socket write or read .

Comment: EAGAIN is normally returned when the socket is in non blocking mode, and the read/write operation would block. Have you activated non blocking mode, while still using the blocking API?

Comment: i just use redisConnect (it is blocking API). But as you said it is normally returned in non blocking mode. Using blocking api should block at the syscall .However it return EAGAIN .

Comment: If you have EAGAIN in blocking mode, check the read timeout - I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: for my case .The server redis.conf `timeout 0` .I Call the redisConnect() that mean the client don't set timeout .In redisBufferRead ` if (errno == EAGAIN && !(c->flags & REDIS_BLOCK)) {/*try later*/}` mean if it is no blocking the EAGAIN is not a error. I doubt it may cause by the buffer size. If many redisCommand     was called weather the client don't clean the buf before ?

Comment: Server side timeout is completely unrelated. I have never mentioned a buffer size issue. I'm only talking about client side timeout. I don't understand your last comment. Do you use multi-threading and try to share the Redis connection over multiple threads? This would not work.

Comment: Yes I use the multiple  threads. I make `rcontext =redisConnect((char*)"127.0.0.1", 6379)` as the globe value .Will use it in other thread (actually my code was based on qemu and get data from the vm guest os to save in db) .As you said share Redis connection don't work ,however ,some data  indeed was successfuly write to the db . no success after some time (so I think may be buf issue or memory error)

Comment: I got a solution (but i think it is ugly) I don't connect in main func. And Connect every func where I need operate the db .(It will be interrupt by EINTR .As to you answer I handle it in the hiredis .It just work fine now )

Answer (score 0):

No clue, but a quick search says that (on Linux kernel) a system call can be interrupted when nothing is wrong and when that happens, the typical thing is to just do it again. My guess, since there is nothing to go on here, is the Redis database or some part of your code isn't handling that situation. http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/lk/lk-4.html

Comment: I am not sure . But when the program start .It can run good. After sometime it break.

Comment: By the way `if(errno == ENITR) do again `.Doesn't help. I can't make a loop to test it. I think there is another reason .But I can't find it.